# How to get Dry Bones to stay dead?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

Once I win a battle against a Dry Bones, he collapses.  But after a few minutes, he'll get back up and I'll have to fight him again.  How can I kill a Dry Bones so that he stays dead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one way to kill dry bones permanently. However, you can only do it in Sandshifter Ruins. You need to open a coffin and have the door fall on the dry bones, then it will disappear and give you a few coins. If you leave the level and then come back, the dry bones will be back.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet been able to do this, and I assume you are not supposed to be able to kill them permanently. In every Mario game that features Dry Bones, he always is able to resurrect - likely to do with the fact that he is already a skeleton, and thus cannot be killed as he is already dead.

Comment: There's sometimes been a way, occasionally difficult/rare; fire attacks in Paper Mario/Thousand Year Door, I thin the Hammer or Tanuki Suit worked in SMB3, cape worked in SMW I believe.

Comment: Ah. I might be completely wrong, then, but I haven't yet found a way to destroy them completely.

Comment: @BenBrocka Dry Bones are immune to fire in this game, but they only game ~13 HP.

Answer (score 1):

In Super Mario 3, it was possible to kill a Dry Bones using a Star or the Hammer Suit ([source](http://www.mariowiki.com/Dry_Bones#Super_Mario_Bros._3)).

However, from the same page it make no mention of how to permanently disable a Dry Bones in Paper Mario: Sticker Star ([source](http://www.mariowiki.com/Dry_Bones#Paper_Mario:_Sticker_Star)), thus I would say there is no way to permanently kill a Dry Bones.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I noticed in regards to Dry Bones is that in certain rooms it is dark when you enter, and the Dry Bones are dead on the floor. As soon as you turn on the lights (by hitting the lamps from underneath) they wake up.

However, when I turned the lights out again they did not die, nor stay dead when killed. It's possible that they only stay dead if the lights are out when you *enter* a room.